# Ubunutu 6.2.0-36 stuck on boot

Tags: boot, error-handling

Yesterday I used normally the computer. However, today the ubuntu out of nowhere doesn’t boot. It’s stuck on this page: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPWQS.jpg)
The journal shows this error: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EOZ6.jpg)
What can I do?

Comment: The computer works just fine as I can still boot into windows. The error just occurs using linux